# What are some resources for optimizing ActionScript (flash) for speed and size

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance

I'm especially interested in memory profiling, reducing the size of a compiled .swf, measuring network latency, etc.  Also, I'm focussed entirely on AS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest [Flex Builder Professional](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/features/flex_builder/) includes both memory and performance profilers built in:

***Powerful testing tools (New in Flex Builder 3) (Professional edition only)***

*The Flex Builder 3 memory and performance profilers enable developers to improve application performance by providing tools to monitor and analyze memory consumption and CPU cycles. Support for automated functional testing tools such as HP QuickTest Professional (formerly Mercury QuickTest Professional) is also now available in Flex Builder 3 Professional.*

It doesn't include network latency -- I haven't heard of built-in tools to do anything like that -- would a [packet sniffer](http://www.wireshark.org/) suit your needs for that?

Answer (score 0):

FlexBuilder Pro definitely seems like a good option.  Downloading the trial now...

This article looks useful too:

http://flexblog.edchipman.ca/?p=7

I'm not actually concerned about measuring network latency, but I am concerned about measuring which parts of my app are slow because of latency, and which parts are slow because of boneheaded AS3.